# Can I set up the Github integration with a Heroku app using the CLI or API?

Tags: heroku

I would like to automate creating a heroku app, and integrate it with Github, so that it will [automatically deploy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration#automatic-deploys) when new commits are pushed to Github.

Is this possible? I've looked through the [Heroku Toolbelt CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/creating-apps) docs and the [Heroku API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/platform-api) docs, and I didn't find any mention of the Github Integration.

Comment: No, that it not currently possible.

Comment: Thanks @DamienMATHIEU. I was afraid that was the case, but I couldn't find any confirmation either way.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the deploy tab of your Heroku Dashboard, you can connect your github directly to it

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do that, but I was asking if it is possible to do programmatically.